# Create XML file on FTP server without creating physical file localy

Tags: java, xml, ftp, jaxb

So I want to make XML file on FTP server. I know, that I can do it localy and later just upload it, but I want to make it without local physical file.

My code to create it locally was:

```
public class XMLFileMaker {
    public void countryObjectsToXML(Employee emp, String path) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlHeaders", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        marshaller.marshal(emp, new File(path + File.separator + "Informations.xml"));
    }
}
```

Somebody have any ideas how can I solve my problem?

(Uploading CSV file I have like here: [Uploading a csv file to ftp without creating a physical file locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526888/uploading-a-csv-file-to-ftp-without-creating-a-physical-file-locally)  But now I don't have idea how to upload XML :/)

Answer (score 0):

FTP is a file transfer protocol, you can move files on server but it does not support file creation. for all available commands type "help" after ftp login.

Comment: But for example CSV I'm making without local representation. I'm making: [code]CSVWriter writer = null; ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); Writer writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos)); writer = nw CSVWriter(writer2); byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray(); ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); client.storeFile(path, bais);[/code] And it works without creating file local :P 
@edit BTW. How can I make my code in [code] in this short answer?

Comment: As you pushed your CSV stream on server same you can push stream of your XML contains.